# How to search for a value, in SQL, through all tables of a database using a temporary stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have multiple databases and I want to create a temporary stored procedure (`##SearchAllTables`) that searches for a value in all tables of a database.

The problem that I am facing is that if I create the temporary stored procedure against the master database, when I run it against another database it does not work as it doesn't display any findings.

If I create the same temp stored procedure against that specific database, it works fine.

I am using the stored procedure from this website:
https://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated/

Do you know why I have this behavior?

Comment: How are you executing the temporary stored procedure? How are you running it against other databases?

Comment: Something like this USE [DBName]
GO
EXEC ##SearchAllTables  @SearchStr = N'stringtest'

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stored procedure, it seems this filter on line 33 of the procedure code is the issue when applied to the `master` database:

```sql
OBJECTPROPERTY(
    OBJECT_ID(
        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
        ), 'IsMSShipped'
            ) = 0
```

The tables in the `master` database all come shipped with MS SQL installation, so will have `IsMSShipped` property equal to 1 and thus be excluded from searching. You can test this by running:

```sql
select
    *,
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped')
from
    master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

If you want to search these tables, remove that filter from the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: This is a VERY intensive task you're asking to do.  I wouldn't recommend running against a production environment.

The code you're referencing is only intended to query tables in the current database.

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns one row for each table or view in the current database for which the current user has permissions.

If you wanted it to run for every database you'd have to modify it to loop through all databases.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @dbName  NVARCHAR(256)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --Code from proc here
END
```

Then you'd need to modify the query that is putting together the @TableName variable to include the database name:

```
...

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT QUOTENAME(@dbName)+ '.' + MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

 ...
```